# Mask tree shape on video view

Tags: android, canvas, mask

I am new in Android development and I want to create one app in which I want to play one video to full height and width of screen, And another video on same screen with tree masking. I mean one video view to full height width of screen and 2nd one in center of the screen and on current video with tree shape. Please any help would be appreciate. Thanks and sorry for my bad English.